# How to enable hyphenation in UITextView with non-English text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, hyphenation

I use `paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1`, but it works fine only for English text. 
How to enable hyphenation in `UITextView` with non-English text or set locale to `UITextView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018581/adding-hyphens-with-cfstringgethyphenationlocationbeforeindex/19858601#19858601) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239267/kerning-in-ios-uitextview) I found solution:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"LOCALE"];
NSString *hyphenatedString = [string softHyphenatedStringWithLocale:locale error:&error];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                        "<head> \n"
                        "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"> \n"
                        "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                        "html {-webkit-hyphens: auto; } \n"
                        "</style> \n"
                        "</head> \n"
                        "<body>%@</body> \n"
                        "</html>", hyphenatedString];


@try {
    SEL setContentToHTMLString = NSSelectorFromString([@[@"set", @"Content", @"To", @"HTML", @"String", @":"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]);
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [textView performSelector:setContentToHTMLString withObject:htmlString];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    textView.text = hyphenatedString;
}
```